# Leave tracker VBA code hide columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim allColumns As Range

    Set allColumns = Columns("D:NK")
    allColumns.Hidden = True

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "1" Then
            Columns("D:AH").Hidden = False
        ElseIf Target.Value = "2" Then
            Columns("AI:BM").Hidden = False
End If
    End If
End Sub
```

but when I am updating sheet all columns are getting hidden.....
I tried using different vba but still not working

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value = 1 Then
    Exit Sub
Else:
    Range("B3").Value = Range("B3").Value - 1
    LeaveTracker.Columns("D:NK").Hidden = True
    LeaveTracker.Range(Columns(Range("B3").Value * 31 - 29), Columns(Range("B3").Value * 31 + 3)).Hidden = False
End If
```

Please help

Comment: Works for me. Are events enabled? Code definitely in the right sheet?

Comment: So all columns in range `D:NK` should be hidden.  When the **1** is entered in cell `B3` then columns `D:AH` should be visible, if **2** is entered in cell `B3` then columns `AI:BM` should be visible.  If any other value is entered then all columns remain hidden.  If that's what' supposed to happen then, as @SJR said, it all works fine.

Comment: hi Darren, vba is working fine, however when I update any column with eg: S=Sick leave or V=Vacation, then all columns (D:NK) gets hidden...and I have to refresh worksheet to get visible columns